# android font has incorect measureText for numerals

Tags: android, graphics, fonts, fontmetrics

measureText() returns the same value for '0' as for '1' using default font in a canvas. is there a font with correct measures?

output from program:

```
12-15 22:36:53.572 28453-28453/acme.measure I/System.out: character: '0' has text bounds: Rect(5, -68 - 48, 1), or 43x69, measure: 53.0
12-15 22:36:53.573 28453-28453/acme.measure I/System.out: character: '1' has text bounds: Rect(7, -67 - 34, 0), or 27x67, measure: 53.0
12-15 22:36:53.573 28453-28453/acme.measure I/System.out: character: 'A' has text bounds: Rect(1, -68 - 61, 0), or 60x68, measure: 62.0
12-15 22:36:53.573 28453-28453/acme.measure I/System.out: character: 'I' has text bounds: Rect(8, -67 - 17, 0), or 9x67, measure: 25.0
12-15 22:36:53.574 28453-28453/acme.measure I/System.out: 01AI bounds are: Rect(5, -68 - 185, 1), or 180x69

package acme.measure;
import android.content.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.*;

import static java.lang.Math.round;
class DrawableView extends View {
    public DrawableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        size=100;
        text="01AI";
        shapeDrawable=new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff000000);
        shapeDrawable.setBounds(0,0,text.length()*size,size);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xffffffff);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        shapeDrawable.draw(canvas);
        Paint paint=new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextSize(size*95/100);
        Rect r=new Rect();
        for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++) {
            paint.getTextBounds(text,i,i+1,r);
            Paint.FontMetrics fontMetrics=paint.getFontMetrics();
            System.out.println("character: '"+text.charAt(i)+"' has text bounds: "+r+", or "+r.width()+"x"+r.height()+", measure: "+paint.measureText(text,i,i+1));
        }
        paint.getTextBounds(text,0,text.length(),r);
        System.out.println(text+" bounds are: "+r+", or "+r.width()+"x"+r.height());
        int x=(text.length()*size-r.width())/2, y=(size-r.height())/2;
        canvas.drawText(text,x,size-y,paint);
    }
    final int size;
    final String text;
    final ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable;
}
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        drawableView=new DrawableView(this);
        layout.addView(drawableView);
        setContentView(layout);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.action_settings)
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    DrawableView drawableView;
}
```

Comment: what does logcat say? what does `getTextBounds` return?

Comment: this is weird: definitely `getTextBounds` gives better results, **but** for " " (space) it returns `Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)` it is a deep mystery...